# How to get CheckBox state changed for multiple checkboxes?

Tags: checkbox, android, android-checkbox

I need to implement somethingh like this, if user will select one checkbox it will hide some component from UI, if user will select another checkbox it will hide some different components from UI. I have implemented this using onCheckedChanged Listner.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (buttonView.getId()){

    case R.id.checkbox_regread:
        if(isChecked){

            btn_reg_rw.setText("Read");
            cb_reg_write.setEnabled(false);

        }else{

            cb_reg_write.setEnabled(true);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.checkbox_regwrite:
        if(isChecked){

            btn_reg_rw.setText("Write");
            cb_reg_read.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
            cb_reg_read.setEnabled(true);
            cb_reg_read.setChecked(false);
        }
        break;
    }
```

But problem i am facing is that i getting the event for `checkbox_rewrite` but not able to get the event for `R.id.checkbox_regread:`. I have check with the Ids, they are correct.

give me any idea why this is happening?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain your problem, I don't understand "But problem i am facing is that i getting the [???] for checkbox_regread"

Comment: When i am selecting the checkbox_regWrite its going into that particular case, but selecting the checkbos_regread the control not going into the particular case.

Comment: From the very limited info you've given us to go on, your switch statement looks to be constructed ok. Have you run a debug with a break point at the start of this switch statement? What happens? Inspect the value of the buttonView parameter when it reaches this break point. What is the value of it's Id, and what is the actual value of R.id.checkbox_regread? Are they different?

Comment: Edit you question by posting part of the code where you defined your listener for your checkbox please.

Comment: Did you set listener to both you checkboxes?

Comment: Thanks, I have missed the listener.